# fputcsv() not including comma in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fputcsv

I am passing an array from Javascript to PHP using AJAX and attempting to write the array as a new line in a CSV file. This row is being appended correctly but isn't including the necessary closing "," at the end.

```
$row = $_POST['row'];
$handle = fopen('filename.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($handle, $row);
fclose($handle);
```

I've tried messing with auto_detect_line_endings but to no success.

Comment: What "necessary" closing `,` at the end? Since when did a csv file terminate lines with a `,`?

Comment: Commas are just put **between** fields. There's no comma after the last field.

Answer (score 2):

A final `,` is not part of the [CSV spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) at all, unless the last field is null or empty.

Also, `fputcsv()` [expects](https://secure.php.net/fputcsv) an array of fields. Is `$_POST['row']` actually an array of fields? You may need to translate your POSTDATA into an appropriate array.